# Get the item ref number on click of button in li of ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of values and a `button` in an `ul`

```
<ul> 
    <li class="mix" category-1="" data-value="600.35" style="display:block;">
        <figure>
            <figcaption>
                <h3>TK</h3>
                <span>LHR</span> 
                <span>LHE</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <span>Sat 28May16</span> 
                <span>
                    18:00
                    <span></span>
                    <span>
                        <i class="fa" fa-clock-o=""></i>
                    </span>
                    7361116644561201001 
                    <div class="clear"></div> 
                    <div class="price-night">
                        <span>1 Stop</span>
                        <span class="price-n">600.35 (£)</span>
                    </div>

                    <button class="info">Buy Now</button>
                </span>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>

    <li class="mix" category-1="" data-value="600.35" style="display:block;">
        <figure>
            <figcaption>
                <h3>TK</h3>
                <span>LHR</span> 
                <span>LHE</span>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <span>Sat 28May16</span> 
                <span>
                    18:00
                    <span></span>
                    <span>
                        <i class="fa" fa-clock-o=""></i>
                    </span>
                    7361116644561201001 
                    <div class="clear"></div> 
                    <div class="price-night">
                        <span>1 Stop</span>
                        <span class="price-n">600.35 (£)</span>
                    </div>

                    <button class="info">Buy Now</button>
                </span>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
<ul/>
```

On click of the `button` I want to get the reference number, outvail, invail total of 3 values, I am using ASP.NET so kindly there is any method I can add single function their too `oncick` call that but how to get the `li` values of `ul`

Comment: Can you please try to reword this to make it more clear as to exactly what you are trying to accomplish, what is not working, and how we can be of assistance?

Comment: YOUR CODE IS NOT FORMATTED AND I DON'T FULLY UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU ARE ASKING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very difficult to follow, but working on the presumption that you need to get the value from the clicked button within a single function, this may help.

```js
$( "ul li" ).click(function() {
  value = $(this).data("value");
  alert( value );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over your items and grab what you need, here an example with your structure:

```js
$(".info").click(function(se,ev)
{
  $.each($(".mix"),function(index,element)
  {
    alert($(element).attr("data-value"));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> <li class="mix" category-1="" data-value="600.35" style="display:block;"><figure><figcaption><h3>TK</h3><span>LHR</span> <span>LHE</span><div class="clear"></div><span>Sat 28May16</span> <span>18:00<span></span><span><i class="fa" fa-clock-o=""></i></span>7361116644561201001 <div class="clear"></div> <div class="price-night"><span>1 Stop</span><span class="price-n">600.35 (£)</span></div>

<button class="info">Buy Now</button></span></figcaption></figure></li>

<li class="mix" category-1="" data-value="600.35" style="display:block;"><figure><figcaption><h3>TK</h3><span>LHR</span> <span>LHE</span><div class="clear"></div><span>Sat 28May16</span> <span>18:00<span></span><span><i class="fa" fa-clock-o=""></i></span>7361116644561201001 <div class="clear"></div> <div class="price-night"><span>1 Stop</span><span class="price-n">600.35 (£)</span></div>

<button class="info">Buy Now</button></span></figcaption></figure></li>
```